# Unittest in Python for method with more than one return values

Tags: python, unit-testing

I would like to create a unittest in Python for a method that has more than one return values. For example let's say I want to test the following method:

```
def example(x, y):
    sum = x + y
    dif = x - y
    return sum, dif
```

Is there any way to have a unittest for this method?
(I know that I can split the above in 2 different methods, but this is just a naive example)

Comment: How does this function cause a problem for unit testing?

Comment: Maybe you are not aware that in Python what you call "returning two values" is actually the return of a tuple object (with two values inside). And you can `assertEqual` with another object like usual. You can also unpack the values first as shown by Alan.

Answer (score 7):

Capture all the return values, then test them individually.

```
...
    numsum,dif = example(5,3)
    self.assertEqual(numsum,8)
    self.assertEqual(dif,2)
```

or, as @sleigh_bells points out compare a tuple to the returned tuple:

```
self.assertEqual(example(5,3),(8,2))
```

Comment: Thanks. I am new in Python and I did not know that you can run the method before the assert one (finding everywhere things like self.assertEqual('foo'.upper(), 'FOO'))

Comment: [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) is a bad variable name to use in Python.

Comment: @DeliriousLettuce Good point.  I had just used the example names from OP.  Updated.

Comment: @AlanHoover No problem, it just seemed like this should be the accepted answer so I thought I'd mention it here.

Answer (score 2):

You could do

```
assertEqual([sum, dif], [expected_sum, expected_dif])
```

According to the Python documentation, this will actually run assertListEqual because two lists are being passed in.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertListEqual

Answer (score 1):

You can define a tuple variable with the expected result and give it to the assert function:

```py
expected_result = (15, 5)
self.assertEqual(example(10,5), expected_result)
```